# PowerPoint 2007: How to get back the missing list of slides on the left hand side?

Tags: gui, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

PowerPoint 2007 used to display a list of miniature slides down the left hand side, which could be used for navigation and cut/paste.

This list has disappeared - any ideas on how to get it back? I've been through every option on the Ribbon, multiple times, and can't seem to find the option to turn this back on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, had to restart PowerPoint, go to "View", then click on "Normal" a few times.

Answer (score 11):

The pane containing the Outline and Slides tabs can be unhidden by dragging the edge of the splitter bar, which is visible on the left hand side of the program window.

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work, try going to the jewel (upper left). At the bottom of the recent document list is the Powerpoint Options button. On the 'Advanced' tab, under the 'Display' list, look at the 'Open all docs...' option. You can tell it to open in the 'Outline, Notes and Slides' option.  After opening and saving the offending file, you should probably change the setting back to 'The view saved in the file' option.

Answer (score -1):

You need to click *Animations*, then click the *Custom Animation* button.

Comment: This doesn't quite explain how this helps.  Can you expand your answer to give more details?